# Windows batch file to exit only if a certain application is not active?

Tags: batch-file

I use a simple iconized batch file to shut down Windows with one click:

`%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -s -t 0`

How can I modify this so it will not shut down if a certain application is running ?

Comment: You might be interested in the command [`tasklist`](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what application did you want to set ? so i choose `firefox.exe` as application and of course you should change it to yours !

```
@echo off
Title %~nx0 to shutdown the computer with condition
Mode 70,8 & Color 0b
Set "MyProcess=firefox.exe"
::****************************************
:Main
ClS
Tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %MyProcess%" 2>nul |find /i "%MyProcess%" >nul
If not errorlevel 1 (Echo. & echo "%MyProcess%" process is running ! & echo.^
In order to shutdown the computer you should stop it and retry again !
) else (
Goto:Shutdown)
echo.
echo press any key to retry again !
pause>nul
Goto :Main
::****************************************
:Shutdown
%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe -s -t 0
::****************************************
```